# Are `typedef` and `struct` inside of a function standard in C?

Tags: c, function, scope, typedef, standards

I used some code like this:

```
void A()
{
    typedef struct B B;
    struct B
    {

    };

    B b;
};
```

`typedef` and `struct` definition inside a function. It compiled with Clang, but I want to know (1) whether they are part of standard or not. And about (2) whether they are limited to be recognized in function scope only.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Yes, the standard allows this, and yes, the name you create this way is only visible inside the function (i.e., it has local scope, just like when you define `int i;`, `i` has local scope).

It's more common, however to do it something like this:

```
typedef struct { 
    /* ... */ 
} B;
B b;
```

Comment: or, if you're really only going to use it once, `struct { /* ... */ } b;` :)

Answer (score 4):

Yes it is allowed.
but you cannot have
function inside a function.

declarations should be done first and later on you can do with your actual code.

you cannot declare after you do some operation inside your function like below

```
void A()
{

int a=0;

a++;    

typedef struct B B;//this is wrong
    struct B
    {

    };

    B b;
};
```

Comment: C89 requires that declarations/definitions precede other statements, but C99 does not.

Comment: @Vijay   could you update the answer according to new standards?

Comment: Also could you please use clearer indentation in your code?