# Trying to copy the contents of one struct to another

Tags: c, struct, header-files

So I have a struct defined in my header file for access across my program. Then I have a separate struct defined in .c file and the objective is to copy the contents of one struct to the other. However when I try to do so I get the error: "error: ‘pcb’ undeclared (first use in this function) reg.PC = pcb.PC;"

```
/* header file */

struct Registers {

  int PC;
  int IR0;
  int IR1;
  int AC;
  int MAR;
  int MBR;
  int Base;

}; struct Registers reg = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
```

```
/* computer.c */

#include <stdio.h>
#include "computer.h"

void process_init_PCB() {
  
  struct PCB {

  int PC;
  int IR0;
  int IR1;
  int AC;
  int MAR;
  int MBR;
  int Base;

  }; struct PCB pcb = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
  
}

void process_set_registers() {
  
  reg.PC = pcb.PC;
  reg.IR0 = pcb.IR0;
  reg.IR1 = pcb.IR1;
  reg.AC = pcb.AC;
  reg.MAR = pcb.MAR;
  reg.MBR = pcb.MBR;
  reg.Base = pcb.Base;

}
```

I've tried inserting extern struct tags in the set registers function but it gave me errors as well.

Like this:

```
void process_set_registers() {
  
  extern struct pcb;

  reg.PC = pcb.PC;
  reg.IR0 = pcb.IR0;
  reg.IR1 = pcb.IR1;
  reg.AC = pcb.AC;
  reg.MAR = pcb.MAR;
  reg.MBR = pcb.MBR;
  reg.Base = pcb.Base;

}
```

Comment: Would you mind taking some time to learn C and to work through an introductory book on it before trying to write C programs?

Comment: `pcb` seems to be a local variable inside the function `process_init_PCB` so it can't be used outside the function

Comment: Having `struct Registers reg = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};` in a header file is not a good idea...

Comment: `struct PCB` is also defined inside a function

Comment: Add [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5590757/631266) to your reading list. Acquire [a rubber duck](https://rubberduckdebugging.com/) and explain your code to it in excruciating detail. Include in your discussion why pcb is of local type `struct PCB` rather than of type `struct Registers`.

Comment: `struct Registers` and `struct PCB` have the same members... so why have two different types?

Comment: This is a for a project school and as far as the instructions made it seem I was to create two different structs for the registers being used by the rest of the program and the PCB.

Comment: the instructions say to create and initialize the PCB in this specific function so that's why the PCB struct is where it is.

Answer (score 1):

As comments mentioned, your variable 'pcb' is local variable, which cannot be accessed in function 'process_set_registers'.

In your code, you declared structure and assigned the values.
You might want a function do that for you.
And sometimes, pointers might will do this for you.

You can make class-like structures with pointers and memory allocations.
Here's possible implementation using pointers to achieve your objective.

ps. I don't see why did you make same struct twice in your code. (Registers ans PCB) Can you explain why?

```c
// main.c

#include <stdio.h>

#include "computer.h"

int main(void)
{
    printf("Global REG\n");
    registers_print(REG);
    printf("\n");

    Registers* temp = create_registers_with_values(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7);
    printf("Temp REG\n");
    registers_print(temp);
    printf("\n");

    printf("Copy Temp REG to Global REG\n");
    registers_copy(REG, temp);
    printf("\n");

    printf("Global REG\n");
    registers_print(REG);

    return 0;
}
```

```c
// computer.h

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct Registers {
  int PC;
  int IR0;
  int IR1;
  int AC;
  int MAR;
  int MBR;
  int Base;
} Registers;

// Global register.
Registers REG_ =
{
    .PC = 0,
    .IR0 = 0,
    .IR1 = 0,
    .AC = 0,
    .MAR = 0,
    .MBR = 0,
    .Base = 0
};
Registers* REG = (Registers*)&REG_;

Registers* create_registers()
{
    // calloc allocates mems and init them to 0.
    Registers* ths = (Registers*)calloc(1, sizeof(Registers));

    return ths;
}

Registers* create_registers_with_values(int PC, int IR0, int IR1, int AC, int MAR, int MBR, int Base)
{
    Registers* ths = (Registers*)calloc(1, sizeof(Registers));

    ths->PC = PC;
    ths->IR0 = IR0;
    ths->IR1 = IR1;
    ths->AC = AC;
    ths->MAR = MAR;
    ths->MBR = MBR;
    ths->Base = Base;

    return ths;
}

void registers_print(Registers* ths)
{
    printf("PC: %d\n", ths->PC);
    printf("IR0: %d\n", ths->IR0);
    printf("IR1: %d\n", ths->IR1);
    printf("AC: %d\n", ths->AC);
    printf("MAR: %d\n", ths->MAR);
    printf("MBR: %d\n", ths->MBR);
    printf("Base: %d\n", ths->Base);
}

void registers_copy(Registers* dest, Registers* src)
{
    memcpy(dest, src, sizeof(Registers));
}
```

[Edit]
computer.h can be splited by declarations and implementations.

```c
// computer.h

// Don't forget to add your header guard!
#ifndef __COMPUTER_H
#define __COMPUTER_H

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct Registers {
  int PC;
  int IR0;
  int IR1;
  int AC;
  int MAR;
  int MBR;
  int Base;
};
typedef struct Registers Registers;

extern Registers REG_;
extern Registers* REG;

extern Registers* create_registers();
extern Registers* create_registers_with_values(int PC, int IR0, int IR1, int AC, int MAR, int MBR, int Base);

extern void registers_print(Registers* ths);
extern void registers_copy(Registers* dest, Registers* src);

#endif
```

```
// computer.c

#include "computer.h"

// Global register.
Registers REG_ =
{
    .PC = 0,
    .IR0 = 0,
    .IR1 = 0,
    .AC = 0,
    .MAR = 0,
    .MBR = 0,
    .Base = 0
};
Registers* REG = (Registers*)&REG_;

Registers* create_registers()
{
    // calloc allocates mems and init them to 0.
    Registers* ths = (Registers*)calloc(1, sizeof(Registers));

    return ths;
}

Registers* create_registers_with_values(int PC, int IR0, int IR1, int AC, int MAR, int MBR, int Base)
{
    Registers* ths = (Registers*)calloc(1, sizeof(Registers));

    ths->PC = PC;
    ths->IR0 = IR0;
    ths->IR1 = IR1;
    ths->AC = AC;
    ths->MAR = MAR;
    ths->MBR = MBR;
    ths->Base = Base;

    return ths;
}

void registers_print(Registers* ths)
{
    printf("PC: %d\n", ths->PC);
    printf("IR0: %d\n", ths->IR0);
    printf("IR1: %d\n", ths->IR1);
    printf("AC: %d\n", ths->AC);
    printf("MAR: %d\n", ths->MAR);
    printf("MBR: %d\n", ths->MBR);
    printf("Base: %d\n", ths->Base);
}

void registers_copy(Registers* dest, Registers* src)
{
    memcpy(dest, src, sizeof(Registers));
}
```

[Note]
Function declaration in C dosen't require to contain the name of its parameters.

Code below,

```c
extern Registers* create_registers_with_values(int PC, int IR0, int IR1, int AC, int MAR, int MBR, int Base);
```

can be like this.

```c
extern Registers* create_registers_with_values(int, int, int, int, int, int, int);
```

Comment: I know, header files shouldn't contain implementations or something like that. But, code above is just an example. Thank you for your comment, though.

Comment: Better, Thank you. But, the _declaration_ of the struct really belongs in the header. You've now got the _definitions_ in a single "compilation unit". That's good! `:-)`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access a local variable directly from the locale of another function. For this you have to extract that variable in a way. These paths can be via return, Reference parameter, or pointer. But here you also need to take into account the lifetime of the variables.

There is no other way to define this variable in the global field. The disadvantage of this is that it may stay in memory until the end of the program. This depends on what you're doing.